# Сравнение возможностей компиляторов MASM и FASM

Tags: ассемблер, компилятор, masm32, fasm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать на MASM и нельзя (или очень трудно) на FASM и наоборот.

Comment: @unior00p, встречный вопрос. 

А что вы хотите программировать на ассемблере?

Comment: Хотелось бы создать высокоуровневый язык программирования. Цель в основном для самообразования.

Comment: @unior00p Ну, ты не оптимально себе поставил тз.Обрати внимание на Теорию трансляции и [bison][1]. Насчет вопроса про Масм и Фасм, без холивара, т.к. отдаю именно предпочтения Фасму; он посовременнее, существует возможность использовать один и тот-же компиль под разные ос, без перекодирования в форматы nasm под *nix. В инете полно форумов на которых подымалась соответствующая тема.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison

Comment: Да, как я и говорил уже, энтузиазм рулит! Вот FASM, к примеру, всем здесь нравится, в отличие от MASM`а. FASM, к тому же еще и кроссплатформенный, опять же, в отличие от мелкосовтовского масма, который сляпан лишь под винду.

Comment: Писать компилятор языка высокого уровня на ассемблере это бестолковая идея(с экономической точки зрения) так как на каждой архитектуре процессора он разный. Проще служебную часть написать на С а грамматику скомпилировать автоматически из БНФ нотации во Flex/Bison. Так можно не спеша за пару месяцев получить первую бету версию, а не пытаться полгода дебагать мутные ассемблерные листинги. 

P.S. В GCC до середины двухтысячных стояли автоматически сгенерированные парсеры.

Comment: @unior00p, Я бы не советовал начинать писать язык программирования на ассемблере. Попробуй написать на с++. По крайней мере я делал так. Так проще написать основную идею. И всегда можно добавить ассемблерного когда, где потребуется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FASM предоставляет более развитую систему макросов, что облегчает восприятие кода и ускоряет процесс разработки.
Хорошая статья по сабжу: http://www.insidepro.com/kk/108/108r.shtml

Comment: Спасибо. А статья актуальная на данный момент? Просто может что то поменялось за десятилетие.

Comment: Поменялось, конечно. Но макросы в FASM по-прежнему рулят.

Comment: а чем в MASM макросы хуже?

Answer (score 5):

Скажем так, MASM - это компилятор от крупной и вполне себе так серьезной фирмы Microsoft, а FASM - это компилятор, созданный энтузиастом, причем, насколько я знаю, только одним( и причем на Assembler`е ) =) Думаю, это о многом говорит вам. Но не подумайте, что я против энтузиазма, я наоборот за него - у энтузиастов порой получается все сделать даже лучше и качественнее, потому что они, как правило, одержимы не прибылью, как крупные компании, а скорее желанием получать удовольствие от своего дела. Но именно тут суть в том, что FASM был создан ОДНИМ человеком, что, в общем-то сложно, а MASM - подразделением Microsoft.